# Problem with a standard Lightning Component tag in my sandbox probably after the Winter'20 Update. Where should I request to fix this issue?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, bug, platform-bug, issue, lightning-progressindicator

Using the following code I am getting two pop-ups if I hover a stage. I also tried these exact codes on other editions(including developer edition). Its working perfectly alright. I even found the bug using chrome console.[two popup tags are created by an event]. Can someone help me like where to raise the request to fix this issue?

```
   <lightning:progressIndicator currentStep="2">
        <lightning:progressStep label="Stage 1" value="1"></lightning:progressStep>
        <lightning:progressStep label="Stage 2" value="2"></lightning:progressStep>
        <lightning:progressStep label="Stage 3" value="3"></lightning:progressStep>
    </lightning:progressIndicator>
```

[image]

pop-ups were overlapping I separated them using CSS.

follwing are the two different pop-ups Elements.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try posting about this on the developer forums on salesforce.com.

Comment: Thank you @PhilW I have posted one. Some asked me to tweet. is it appropriate?

Comment: I don't know - I work for an ISV (a Salesforce partner) so I have access to a different channel for reporting issues. I dare say if you are on Twitter there's no harm in tweeting Salesforce.